# Whats the best Windows Server platform to run Apache / PHP / MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache-2.2

Anyone out there running this setup ? What is the best Windows Server setup to keep it running smooth ?

Thans

Comment: Er... Linux? For stability, freeness and betterness. 'nuf said.

Comment: For production? VMWare and LAMP? Did you take a look at how to solve the security issues in Xampp/Wamp?

Comment: I agree, and would be using the LAMP box I am working on... except im being forced to migrate ALL LAMP projects to a windoze box... :/

Comment: This is why I cannot use it... :(

Comment: Aww :-( I feel your pain.

Answer (score 3):

Erm...Server 2008 R2 64-bit is a bit of a generic answer but it's the right one, if you want the best Windows server release, well that's it. Obviously you'll have to decide the particular version (Standard, Enterprise etc.) for your system but that's the only answer I think you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

I very much like the product USBWebserver: http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/
This package combines PHP and MySQL (+ PhpMyAdmin) in one simple package. Simply start the .exe and the product starts php and mysql on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Try Xampp. It is easy and smooth running on all platforms. Check [this](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) out.

Comment: On a Windows Server ? is that the best option ?

Is it robust enough ?

Comment: I will vote +1 for Wamp over Xampp

Comment: Im using WAMP fine on my local dev machine, but its not a soluition for a live production box...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php) the best tool for Apache, PHP, Mysql. I am using it since 3 years its great so far